# Pronunciation of PhD

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations, letter-writing

Why is PhD read as /piːeɪtʃˈdiː/ (from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phd)) and not, for example, like /fˈdiː/ , while diagraph *ph* is read as /f/ in Latin and Greek words?  Why do we write *Ph* if not to represent the /f/ sound?

There are questions about writing ([like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25685/)) but not pronouncing.

**EDIT**: Thanks for answers. To be clear.  I asked this because of it is not the three letters P.h.D.  Why we read it not as /ɛf diː/?

Comment: To be consistent, you'd either read each letter (P - h - D) or treat it as a pseudo-word (*fad*). By convention, *Ph.D* is read as individual letters.

Comment: Well, the reason it’s not /fdiː/ is that syllable-initial /fd/ is not phonotactically valid in English, so that’s not a possible pronunciation of anything. It’s a good question, though. There’s no obvious way to pronounce initialisms with digraph letters, so why one strategy was chosen over another is an interesting conundrum.

Comment: In English, the initial consonant cluster of /fd/ is impossible, and would never occur to a native speaker. I have heard it pronounced [fɨd], with a minimum vowel, but just as a joke.

Comment: I've heard the same as @JohnLawler here in the UK, generally by holders of PhDs in a slightly self-deprecating sense

Comment: Oxford University, mainly because of "not invented here" syndrome, calls its PhD degrees DPhil, pronounced /diː fɪl/. Maybe you'd prefer that.

Comment: Please, just migrate ELL questions to ELL.  NO NEED for answers or discussion.

Comment: It is ... profoundly, just amazingly, tedious .. when questions appear on here which have the underlying concept "LOGICALLY such and such in English 'should' be pronounced / spelled / written / etc how I think!  I'm shocked, shocked, that this is not the case!"    How do you reply to this?

Comment: You can call NaCl enn-ay-see-ell, or you can call it sodium chloride, or you can call it salt, but you can't call it nackel.

Comment: @Fattie This is not an ELL question by any possible stretch of the imagination. No amount of learning English will teach you why _PhD_ is pronounced as it is, and the answer is not one that any English speaker will know by dint of being an English speaker. You may find it tedious, but it is actually a very interesting and profound question that is very much an ELU question.

Comment: I posted as a a comment to an answer, but maybe it belongs here instead. In my experience, it's a "sci-dee" and an "ed-dee" for ScD and EdD.

Comment: My insurance agent pronounced it "phud" but that is highly unofficial!

Comment: hi @JanusBahsJacquet "pH" and **many** first-two-letters-symbols (think scientific symbols, elements etc) are "spelled out" as individual letters.   It's a total non-issue.  Janus, you say the question is "interesting" but, there are absolutely no answers to it whatsoever below.  Because, it's totally uninteresting.   :)   Further the tenor of the back and fore is that it  "should" be pronounced some way, which his just silly of course.)  Some words become words (radar) some stay as letters (Lol), some are changing (led lights, already said as a word in say German).   Who Cares?

Comment: @MichaelKay Brilliant! I will henceforth ask table companions to "pass the nackel"!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

PhD (or Ph. D.) is a bit of a frozen expression or idiom. The expression doesn't abbreviate the English phrase "Doctor of Philosophy". If it did, then it would be something like "DP" or "DoP". Instead, PhD retains the structure of the medieval Latin [*Philosophiae Doctor*, which dates from the 17th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy#Medieval_and_early_modern_Europe).

As to why the Latin abbreviation for "Philosophiae" was "Ph" rather than just "P"?  "Philosophia" was a word borrowed into Latin from the Greek, and in Greek the word is spelled "φιλοσοφία", the first letter being ***φ***. In Greek that's a single letter representing an aspirated π, and is transliterated into Latin as ***ph***.

Since the abbreviation PhD does not match up with the English phrase it supposedly abbreviates, the pronunciation of the abbreviation has diverged from the pronunciation of the phrase.

Comment: So the reason the abbreviation for "*F*ilosophy *D*octor" is not pronounced "Eff Dee" is because medieval English scholars liked Latin way too much?

Comment: @Joker_vD More like late Renaissance German scholars, but yeah.

Comment: "that's a single letter representing an aspirated π" ... or at least it was at some time in Greek history.  Even after the Greek pronunciation  of φ changed, the Latin transliteration *ph* was retained.

Comment: As a Greek, I can safely upvote this.

Comment: @Joker_vD: In a similar vein, ECG can be spelled EKG  because it's an abbreviation for Electro**Cardio**Gram and using a K retains the correct pronunciation of the C. Note that both spelling and pronunciation can be affected, or only one of them (some doctors write ECG but say EKG and afaik that is also accepted) Abbreviations sometimes introduce ambiguity (such as the P in "PH", or the C for a "K/S") and therefore the abbreviation is adjusted to remove the introduced ambiguity.

Comment: @Flater *ElectroCardioGram* is pronounced EKG in English because it was invented by Germans, who habitually don't use the letter *c* for anything.

Comment: *then it be something like "DP" or "DoP"* - Note that Oxford University (and possibly others?) awards [DPhil](https://uni-of-oxford.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/185/~/what-is-a-dphil%3F) instead of PhDs

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Most Germans habitually use the letter c for a great many things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I should have been more clear; my last name is an obvious counter-example of my claim. Germans generally don't use *c* as the *initial letter* of a word. At least not in any native-words (e.g. *Cello* doesn't count).

Comment: Do you know when this pronunciation was adopted by/ossified in English, or whether, historically, PhD was ever pronounced "phi D" (fie/fee dee), "phil D", or "PD" in any English-speaking country? I'm curious because in the US, academia-affiliated organizations with the Greek letter Phi in their name either pronounce it in full or abbreviate it to just P (e.g. Alpha Phi Omega is sometimes APO and sometimes A Phi O; Phi Beta Kappa is always PBK). I've never heard of one using PH ("pee aitch"). And then there is the "C Phil" degree, which my alma mater awards on the way to the PhD, not the PhilD.

Answer (score 23):

Because it is an **[initialism](https://www.bing.com/search?q=initialism&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)** so you read out each letter ("DVD" is pronounced "*dee-vee-dee*", not "*dvid*"; "US" is pronounced "*you-ess*", not "*uhs*"). Your proposed pronunciation could be used were it an **[acronym](https://www.bing.com/search?q=acronym&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=acrony&sc=8-6&sk=&cvid=09E125FCEEA74137A946BC65862C8208)**.

Comment: Well, PhD isn't a strict English initialism since Ph isn't an English letter. This answer rather begs the question, why do we consider PhD an initialism and not an acronym?

Comment: Likely to distinguish it from other more comment "P-D" abbreviations, like "police department" or "private detective;" the "H" is likely explicitly called out as a courtesy to the listener, like the phrase "Phat as in p-h"

Comment: But even PD isn't an English initialism for Doctor of Philosophy. If it were, it would be DP or DOP.  It retains the structure of the original Latin *Philosophiae Doctor* which predates the other "PD" abbreviations by a long while, so it can't just be "courtesy to the listener".

Comment: Now to clarify whether one says "P, aitch, D" or "P, hetch, D".

Comment: Who says "hetch" for H?

Comment: @AzorAhai   ... heatchans ...

Comment: PhD is not the only such example. Some English universities award the degree of Doctor of Science and use the abbreviation ScD = pronounced, as in the case of Phd, as three letters.

Comment: @AzorAhai, I've often heard Australians pronounce h as -h(long a)tch-, as in haytch. For example, H.264 - haytch dot 2 6 4.

Comment: @Tracy Yes, that's typically the case (though personally I'd probably still spell it out as 'aitch')

Comment: @TracyCramer regional dialects are fascinating. Californian here, and we'd probably drop the period when pronouncing that one: aitch two six four

Comment: @TracyCramer But who says "hetch"? And what is H.264?

Comment: The distinction between "acronym" and "initialism" is not clear cut, and some terms can be pronounced either way depending on the speaker (e.g. "SQL"). At best, it *describes* the fact that "PhD" is pronounced as letters, but it doesn't *explain why*. This answer is like saying "the sky is blue because the word blue refers to the colour of the sky".

Comment: @AzorAhai "Who says "hetch" for H" - In the UK , only people 'oo don't know 'ow to talk proper. ;)

Comment: It's not really an initialism.   In classic ELU style, this just adds confusion on confusion  :)

Comment: @AzorAhai, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC

Comment: In my circle, other kinds of Ds pronounce the kind of D. it's a "sci-dee" and an "ed-dee" for ScD and EdD.

Comment: @AzorAhai According to [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/h), the Irish pronunciation of "h" is like "haytch" (choose Irish from the dropdown and you'll hear it). I can't vouch for it though, I'm just reporting it.

Comment: @FabioTurati Okay, that's good to know. But I was asking about "hetch."

Comment: @AzorAhai 'hetch' sounds upper-crusty.  Those who own horses and pronounce girl 'gel' ... maybe.